# Android - Selecting video from gallery - How to only allow videos under 1 minute?

Tags: android, video

In my android app I allow users to select videos from gallery via

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("video/*");
```

Is there a way to only allow users to select videos under 1 minute in length? Or do I have to check video length once it is already loaded in memory? If so, can you point me to some code that could accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to get uri of video. On result callback, u will have video uri. Use this code to check duration:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
//use one of overloaded setDataSource() functions to set your data source
retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time );

retriever.release()
```